# htaccess 404 redirect problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

htaccess 401 redirect problem

My problem is that my 404 redirect to my index.htm file is not working. The only way I can get it to work is by removing the addtype application line below, but I need this for an included left navigation on the site. Any help would be great thank you.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$
RewriteRule .* products/noimage.jpg [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cases.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cases.com/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
# Rewrite Rule for blog.cases.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog.cases.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php .htm
```

Comment: You mean 301 redirect, right? (As your code indicates.)

Comment: no 404 redirect for example if there is a broken link i want them to get redirected to the index.htm page but because of the addtype application line i just says "no input file specified" here is and example [link]http://www.cases.com/1234.htm, I need it it be redirected to index.htm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5219937/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but some others had some conflicts using the AddType.  Some variations that seemed to work for people are added below.  Before trying and changing the AddType, put the complete file name in the 404 redirect.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.htm
```

**EDIT:**

I just tried your file, and I can't reproduce your issue.  I looked at [your hosting company's docs](http://support.verio.com/documents/view_article.cfm?doc_id=3624) and you have it correct.  The one thing I do see them mention is [multiple extensions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext), and then takes you to a place showing the code (below) which you said didn't work

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|htm|html)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

They do show in the documentation the full domain listed and specifically mention **"filename of the .html file"** as shown below.

```
Custom Error Messages

Add the following to the .htaccess file: 

ErrorDocument 404 http://forexample-domain.com/error.html


After "ErrorDocument", specify the error code, followed by a space, and then the path and filename of the .html file you would like to be displayed when the specified error is generated.
```

Source: http://support.verio.com/documents/view_article.cfm?doc_id=3624

If those don't work, then it probably is something with your hosting company.  doesn't make to much since to me, and even if I tried to reproduce, couldn't.  Sorry...

Comment: none of these solved the problem, like I said it all works when I take out 

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php .htm


but then the left nav disappears.  If it help I'm hosted on verio

Comment: I think the reason you can reproduce the problem is you need to specify .htm for example [link]www.cases.com/1324.htm[link] this says "No Input File Specified". But [link]www.cases.com/1234[link] works.  This is very strange.

Comment: Working exactly as expected for me.  No variations would cause it to say 'No Input File Specified'.